# Tags for both [publishing] and [publication]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have the following two tags which, at least from their names, seem pretty similar:

- [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing), 12 questions

  > Questions about current or historical practices in publishing.
- [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication), 11 questions

  > For questions about the publication of a work, not the text of the work itself.

Perhaps there *is* a difference between these two tags and how they are (or should be) used, but the tag wiki excerpts, quoted above, aren't making it clear.

1. **Should these two tags be merged?** Are they, in fact, describing the same thing?
2. **If not, what's the difference?** And can we edit the tag wikis to reflect that difference? Including explicit references to each other in the wikis, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need a [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag as described in Tsundoku's [answer](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1040/289). However, I believe that it is confusing to also have a [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) tag. In practice I think we see many questions tagged as one which should be tagged as the other.

All questions about specific publications of a work fall under the more general category of text editing:

- When was a work first published?
- What was the publication format?
- Were there illustrations? How were they used?
- Are there manuscript sources for this work? If so, are there discernible differences between the manuscript sources and the print publication?
- Are there multiple printed versions / editions that differ significantly?
- What accounts for differences between the various manuscript and printed versions of the work? Authorial revision? Censorship? Printing error?
- Is this work a written representation of folktales or myths that were originally part of an oral tradition? If so, when did this transition to a written text occur?

The questions raised by text editing are pretty important for literary scholars and students. I propose that we use a [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) tag to replace [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication). This new tag also supersedes the current [editions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editions), because the topics covered by that tag also are part of a work's textual history.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is possible to make a distinction, but there is likely going to be some overlap:

- [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) would cover questions such as, when a specific book was published, in what form or what type of edition, possibly in what year and by whom (typically for older works, when there is some uncertainty), in other words how a publication came into existence as a *publication* (which involves a publisher), not as a text (which usually does not involve a publisher).
- [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) would cover publishing practices in a specific place (city, country, ...) and era. Questions with this tag would mention specific works only as examples.

Since publishing practices always affect the way a certain work was turned into a publication, there will be some overlap. For example, [Why weren't Blake's poems published in their original painted form?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5579/2191) is both about the original publication and about publishing practices, so both tags would be relevant here.

In the question [What does “Printed for…” mean?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5386/2191), the example cited in the question is merely illustrative, so only the [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag is appropriate here.

Questions tagged [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) are about whether certain works ever got published, when they were published, etcetera. The [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag, as defined above, would not be appropriate here. (Exception: [Why don't the modern printings of Campion novels use the original artwork?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/359/2191) should be tagged [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) based on the above definitions.)

---

Below are draft tag wiki excerpts for the two tags:

**Publishing**

> Questions about current or historical practices in publishing that affected or would affect many or most publications in a specific period and/or place (country, city, ...). In this type of questions, specific works may be cited as examples. However, for questions concerning the publication of specific works, use the [publication] tag.

**Publication**

> Questions about the publication of a work, not the text of the work itself. This type of questions asks about how a specific text came into existence as a publication (which involves a publisher), not as a text (which usually does not involve a publisher. Valid examples are when or in what form a specific work was published and by whom. For publishing practices of a specific country or time period, use the [publishing] tag.

Comment: Could you write up some draft tag wikis and excerpts for these proposed tag meanings (including referencing each tag in the other's wiki) and edit them into your answer? I think you're drawing a good distinction here, but it'd be nice to see how it works in practice, and whether the difference between the tags can be stated **clearly** enough to avoid misuse but still **briefly** enough to fit in a tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I added two drafts. The first one should be short enough; I'm not sure about the second one.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have submitted both drafts as tag wiki excerpts. It turned out that the length was OK.

Answer (score 2):

### Questions tagged [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) that should be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history)

- [Horatio Hornblower book as part of anthology](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16877/289)
- [Who classified Tagore's songs into the six standard categories?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16518/289)
- [What is the original source of Tagore's "Endless Time"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16222/289)
- [Info about *Wisdom is One* by Benjamin Williams Huntsman?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14981/289)
- [Why is the order of *The Chronicles of Narnia* changed from original publication?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14952/289)
- [Which short stories are falsely attributed to Maupassant, and why?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14259/289)
- [When were the short stories of *Malgudi Days* originally published?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13907/289)
- [When was each article in *Avowals and Denials* written?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9549/289)
- [When was Marlowe's *Dr Faustus* written?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8969/289)
- [Where can I find details on the original mss of the Miyamoto Musashi texts?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8593/289)
- [Was *The Forty Rules of Love* originally written in Turkish or English?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8470/289)
- [Why was *Far from the Madding Crowd* originally published anonymously?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8309/289)
- [How many Shakespearean or Jacobean mss of Shakespeare's Sonnets have come down to us?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8116/289)
- [How was *Crime and Punishment* originally published?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6784/289)
- [Why were *Daisy-Head Mayzie* and *My Many Colored Days* not published until after Dr Seuss's death?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6425/289)
- [Have Kenneth Muir's poems ever been published as a collection?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5382/289)
- [In what year was Heine's "Frühlingsbotschaft" published?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5280/289)
- [In which year was Hesse's "Frühling" published?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5277/289)
- [Did Viktor Frankl ever publish his manuscript?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2062/289)
- [When did Frost write "Two Tramps in Mud Time"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1683/289)
- [Did Cummings' editors try to fix his works' eccentricities?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1181/289)
- [Why did *Some Answered Questions* get retranslated?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/433/289)
- [Why don't the modern printings of Campion novels use the original artwork?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/359/289)
- [When did Gerrit de Veer publish his diary?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/121/289)

### Questions tagged [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) that need to be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) and have an *additional* [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag

- [Use of Fraktur in 19th C. English Print](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8911/289)
- [Why would one of Germany's leading publishers publish a novel by Stefan Zweig in 1939?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17185/289)

### Questions tagged [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) that need to be retagged [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing)

- [Why didn't the publisher advertise *The Ballad of Songbirds and Snakes* more heavily?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14713/289)

Comment: (This answers lists ALL questions tagged `publication`. The proposed change would abolish the `publication` tag, largely replacing it with `textual-history`.)

Comment: Thumbs up for the proposed retaggings in these lists.

Comment: These have all been retagged as suggested, with a few manual edits and a mod tag merge.

Answer (score 1):

### Questions tagged [editions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editions) that should be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history)

- [When and how was the manuscript of Fratricide Punished lost?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15522/289)
- [Earliest known manuscripts of the Shahnameh?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15471/2890)
- [What manuscript(s) was the first printed edition of *The Tale of Genji* based on?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15147/289)
- [Why are there three different versions of "solid/sallied/sullied flesh in *Hamlet*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15062/289)
- [Was it traditional to omit the prologue from Shakespeare's plays in the First Folio?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14947/289)
- [How do scholars estimate the original number of copies of the First Folio?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14710/289)
- [How do we know whether or not a given Nietzsche work has been edited by his sister?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14561/289)
- [Which version of *How to Read a Book* is better?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14342/289)
- [In *It*, is Derry, ME, said to be named after Derry or Londonderry?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/13780/289)
- [Who edited the second edition of Tesla's autobiography?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12530/289)
- [What manuscript was the first printed edition of the *Odyssey* based on?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12256/289)
- [Empty pages in *Kongens Fald*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12030/289)
- [Has Conrad's "The Duel" been published in any recent short story collections?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11824/289)
- [Which of these sources is right about *The Tempest*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11173/289)
- [Is there a useful "entry-level" annotated *Le Morte d'Arthur*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11015/289)
- [Are all editions of Mann's *Joseph und seine Brüder* the same?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11009/289)
- [Is there really a single "Old Babylonian version" of *Gilgamesh*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9007/289)
- [*Fight Club* editions and differing passages](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8705/289)
- [Is there any difference between *The Motorcycle Diaries* Ocean Press edition and the film tie-in edition?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8350/289)
- [What texts are the sources for the difference between "sometime were" and "some time are" in *Julius Caesar*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6745/289)
- [Differences between translations of *The Art of War*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6725/289)
- [What is the "full" version of *Gilgamesh*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6365/289)
- [What typographical methods have been used to distinguish the two strands of *The Never-ending Story*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5932/289)
- [Why does Kipling's "The Three-Decker" differ between editions?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5793/289)
- [Difference between 2016 editions of *A Game of Thrones*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5675/289)
- [Unabridged pre-1923 edition of *Le Morte d'Arthur*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5417/289)

### Questions tagged [editions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editions) that need to be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) and need an *additional* [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tag

- [How can I find information about the editions of a book?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6606/289)
- [Why does Great Illustrated Classics change details in its abridged versions?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8695/289)
- [Are Barnes and Noble editions of public domain works of reliable quality?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15227/289)
- [Which is the "true" first edition of a book?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14370/289)

### Questions tagged [editions](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editions) that need to be retagged [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing)

- [Classics published in the language of the author](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14750/289)

Comment: (This answer lists ALL questions tagged `editions`. The proposed change would abolish the `editions` tag, largely replacing it with `textual-history`.)

Comment: These have all been retagged as suggested, with a few manual edits and a mod tag merge.

Answer (score 1):

### Questions tagged [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) that should be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history)

- [Why weren't Blake's poems published in their original painted form?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5579/289)

### Questions tagged [publishing](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) that need an *additional* [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) tag

- [Why would Image Comics publish *Sunstone* after it was released as a web comic?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4103/289)
- [What typographical methods have been used to distinguish the two strands of *The Never-ending Story*](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5932/289)

Comment: (This answer lists *only those questions* tagged `publishing` that would be affected by the addition of `textual-history`. These questions are mistagged or incompletely tagged.The other questions with the `publishing` tag are fine.)

Comment: These few questions have all been retagged as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

### Questions tagged [oral-tradition](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-tradition) that need an *additional* [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) tag

- ["Yum Yum Pig's Bum"](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15876/289)
- [How did the story of Robin Hood pass from oral literature to written?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9449/289)
- [How long did accounts of the Sängkreig last as purely oral literature?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3565/289)
- [Were any of the Asbjørnsen og Moe stories transcribed directly from oral traditions?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2359/289)
- [Are there any recorded discrepancies between The Odyssey as oral tradition and The Odyssey as Homer transcribed it?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2142/289)
- [What's the first appearance of the rhyme about “He died defending his right of way”?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18230/289)

### Questions tagged [oral-tradition](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oral-tradition) that need *either* that tag removed *or* an additional [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history) tag

- [Who collected Dandilion's songs in written books?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/12388/289)

Comment: (This answer lists only those questions tagged `oral-tradition` that would be affected by the addition of `textual-history`. These questions are mistagged or incompletely tagged.The other questions with the `oral-tradition` tag are fine.)

Comment: These few questions have been retagged as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

### Questions tagged [history-of-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-literature) that need to be retagged [textual-history](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textual-history)

- [When and why did “No man is an island” start being regarded as a poem?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17993/289)
- [When was Mem and Zin / Mam û Zîn first printed?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/17968/289)
- [Matthew Arnold's anthology of literature for use in schools](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14610/289)
- [How did the story of Robin Hood pass from oral literature to written?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9449/289)
- [Is there really a single “Old Babylonian version” of the Epic of Gilgamesh?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9007/2890)
- [Use of Fraktur in 19th Century English Print](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/8911/289)
- [What texts are the sources for the difference between “sometime were” and “some time are” in Shakespeare's Julius Caesar?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6745/289)
- [What's the origin of the rhyme “My friend Billy had a ten foot willy”?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5395/289)
- [How many manuscripts of English Renaissance plays have survived?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4954/289)
- [First book of Edward de Vere's poems?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/4925/289)
- [Why was the text of “HaTikvah” changed?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2871/289)
- [What is the origin of this contradictory poem?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2193/289)
- [How long have the cantillation marks been around?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1370/289)

**Note:** Some of these have already been mentioned in the [publication](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publication) and [edition](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edition) answers.

Comment: (This answer lists only those questions tagged `history-of-literature` that would be affected by the addition of `textual-history`. These questions are mistagged or incompletely tagged.The other questions with the `history-of-literature` tag are fine.)

Comment: These questions have been retagged as suggested.